# How to run synthesized VHDL code on Xilinx Zynq-7000 All Programmable SoC ZC702 Evaluation Kit (FPGA SDSoC)

Tags: sdk, vhdl, fpga, vivado, zynq

In my work I have to prove that the synthesized C++ visual algorithm code in VHDL (made via Vivado HLS) running on FPGA part on Zynq702 from Xilinx is quicker then  classic C++ code on conventional CPU.

The main problem witch I am not able to resolve is - how is possible to "load" the synthesized code into SDK tool from Vivado 2016 tool, in other words - how is possible to run the synthesized VHDL code (bitstream) on the board?

In my opinion, the SDK program is only for C / C++ code. Is there any way how can I get the bitstream of VHDL code on the processor and prove that the synthesized code running on FPGA is quicker then the original C++ code?

Can you give me an advise ? I went through several YouTube tutorials and forums but it didn't help me.

Comment: Basically, Translate/Map/Place and Route on the classic tools, they are probably renamed in Vivado. In other words it won't run on the processor at all. It'll run ot the FPGA fabric.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically you need two versions of your code. One C/C++ version meant to run on the CPU and a version in C/C++ (slightly adapted) to use with HLS (targeting programmable logic) .

Xilinx offers a tool named SDSoC which does that for you. Basically you write your application once in C/C++. A profiler tells you which function uses most computational power and you can mark these functions to be off-loaded to programmable logic. The tool will use Vivado HLS in the background to convert your C/C++ to RTL code. SDSoC will tell you what the expected speedup is compared to the original code which runs entirely in the CPU.

I would suggest you to read through [UG1028](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_3/ug1028-sdsoc-intro-tutorial.pdf)

Comment: Waw! 
It is my bachelor project and I was totally lost how to do it even I saw many videos on YT and red quite enough materials, but in each manual it was represented in other way - I mean trough HLS -> Vivado -> SDK. So I was confused what I really need to use and how. 

 
Many thanks, really. 
Adriana

Comment: @AdriankaBeno , SDSoC is a fairly new tool. many of the documentation online will show you how to do it before SDSoC existed. To keep up-to-date with the latest Xilinx tech i would suggest to regularly read XCell Daily Blog.

Comment: Thank you for your help, we currently wait for licence for SDSoC, but in the case, the license will be not accepted, is there any way how to make a hardware design in Vivado 2016.4 working trough the workflow VIVADO HLS - VIVADO - SDK? @Robbie Vincke this is our current state, as you can see, video_in is not connected. http://prntscr.com/exshqk Therefore is not possible to generate correct bitstream. Can You please suggest any missing components in this design ? The IP part is HLS fast corner detection algorithm. 

Thank you so much.

Comment: The workflow is as followed:
1) Write your HLS corner detection alghm in HLS. 2) Export the generated IP to the IPcatalog and include in your block-level design. 3) Export the Hardware to SDK and write the sw app running on the CPU. 

In your blockdesign i don't see any high-perf. bridge enabled on the CPU. This is needed for your VDMA IP to push/fetch videodata from ddr. That means the M_AXI_MM2S and M_AXI_S2MM of your VDMA should be connected (using a AXIInterconnect) to S_AXI_HP0 on the CPU. 

PS. If the above answer was helpful, can you please accept it as an answer to your question?

Comment: Dear Robbie, 
thank you for your help and time. I appreciate it so much!

Please, could you give me a feedback about this scheme - is it correct yet please ?  The link is here: http://prntscr.com/eya4xj

Also we have successfully generated the bitstream and exported to SDK, but we do not know how to verify the correctness.
Have you any idea, please, how to run the bitstream  on FPGA in SDK program? Or if you have any tutorials, it will help us so much, cause this "end part" of the full process is missing us, so we do not have any output or report.

Anyway, thank you so much
Adriana

Comment: Use a separate AXI interconnect for HP0 and GP0. First AXI interconnect comes from M_AXI_GP0 to 1 slave port of interconnect and the master ports connect to the control buses of all peripherals. 
The second AXI interconnect has 2 slave ports connected to VDMA and the master port connected to S_AXI_HP0.
To avoid too much spamming on this closed question you can contact me directly (LinkedIn, ...)